# Comparing numbered urls in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

"In urls.py I have:

```
path("viewer/<str:case>", views.viewer, name="viewer"),
```

This works when I go to the viewer:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle {% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "viewer" %}active{% endif %}">
```

Now, there is a submenu in nav bar that lists cases.
I need to know which specific page I'm on to make one of menu items active:

```
{% for item in cases %}   
<li>
  <a class="dropdown-item {% if request.get_full_path == "/viewer/{{ item.id }}" %}active{% endif %}" href="/viewer/{{ item.id }}">{{ item.patient_name }}</a>
</li>
```

request.get_full_path returns /viewer/47 for example and one of the item's id is 47. I've tried different combinations instead of "/viewer/{{ item.id }}", nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom template tag:

```
tags.py:
@register.simple_tag
def url_case_id(value):
    return int(value.split("/")[2])
```

and using it in html:

```
{% for item in cases %}  
{% url_case_id request.get_full_path as id %} 
<li>
  <a class="dropdown-item {% if id == item.id %}active{% endif %}" href="/viewer/{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
</li>
```